# How do you Mocha test if else statements?

Tags: node.js, if-statement, mocha.js

I am having trouble trying to write a Mocha test for an if else statement in Node.js. Here is what is being tested:

```
exports.restrict = function(req, res, next) {
    if (req.session.user) {
    next();
  } else {
    req.session.error = 'Access denied!';
    res.redirect('/login');
    }
}
```

This is how I am trying to test it:

```
describe('interface', function(){        
it('should show ability to asynchronously deny a user with an incorrect password', function(done){
        function restrict (req, res, next){
            if (req.session.user) {
                next();
                done();
            } else {
                req.session.error.should.equals('Access denied'); 
                req.redirect.should.equals('/login'); 
                done();
            }
        }
    });
});
```

The error I receive when running the test is that it say timeout because it exceeds 2000ms. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

In your test you define a `restrict` function which is never called, so `done` is never called and the test times out. This is what you are doing wrong. There's nothing special to using `if... else` in Mocha tests.

Wider issue: what you show in your question suggests that you duplicate the code of your module into your test suite. That's a terrible way to go about testing code. You should structure your module so that your test suite is able to exercise its functions without duplication of code.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there was a incorrect statement in your test file. Reading your source file, we have two scenarios to check for `restrict` function.

1. if user session exist, check if `next()` is called
2. if user session not exist, check if `redirect()` is called and `req.session.error` is assigned

Based on top bullets, we can design our test such as

```
const sinon = require('sinon');
const chai = require('chai');
const assert = chai.assert;

const src = require('./src');

describe('interface', function () {
  it('calls next() if user session exist', function () {
    const next = sinon.spy();
    const res = sinon.spy();
    const req = {
      session: {
        user: 'username' // set user session
      }
    }

    src.restrict(req, res, next);    

    assert(next.called);
  });

  it('redirects if user session not exist', function () {
    const next = sinon.spy();
    const res = {
      redirect: sinon.spy()
    }
    const req = {
      session: {}      
    }

    src.restrict(req, res, next);    

    assert.equal(req.session.error, 'Access denied!');
    assert(res.redirect.calledWith('/login'));

    assert.isFalse(next.called)
  });
});
```

we don't need to use `done()` because `restrict()` is not async function. 
We also use `sinon` here to spy `req`, `res` and `next` variable.

Ref:
 - https://sinonjs.org/

Hope it helps.